# Why did this data type conversion happen in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, type-conversion

I have a table which stores webpage performace stats, including timestamps of request start and end times for each user. The timestamp is saved as an INT field in the database but sent as a string from the front-end to PHP, which in turn did some behind-the-scenes type conversion for me and turned every timestamp into the following INT:

```
2147483647
```

Now, the problem was solved by converting the original input to an integer on the fly, so my question is not how to fix this but rather **why** did this exact conversion happen and why is this its output? This has been tested with a variety of timestamp strings but all of them returned the same output:

```
1515153744264 -> 2147483647
```

So dear knowledgable esoteric SQL wizard people, what is happening here on a lower level?

Comment: Because `2147483647` is a max value for your field type?

Comment: Makes sense, didn't know about this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save the value the `string` must be converted to an `int`. And the max value of `int` is `2147483647`

Comment: (when using 32-bit PHP) which should still be valid for a unix timestamp until 19th January 2038, but if that timestamp is milliseconds instead of second?!?

Comment: 1515153744264 is actually milliseconds; divide by 1000 to get 1515153744, which is 5th January 2018 @ 12:02 (UTC).... If you need millisecond precision, divide by 1000 and store as a float